# Get distinct values and filter ResultSet without writing a loop?

Tags: scala, jdbc

I have a stored procedure returns a list of rows and I need to filter the returned result set (`rs`) by the individual value from a column in `rs`.

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcSqlConn)

// rs has a column of `Category`
val rs = conn.createStatement.executeQuery(s"exec getRows $id")

// Get distinct Category values from rs
val categories = // distinct value of column Category 
                 // How to do it without iterating over the rows?

// For each category in categories
//     get the rows filtered by category (where rs.Category = category)
//        and save it to rsFiltered
       val writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(s"fileName_$category"))
       writer.writerAll(rsFiltered, true) // rsFiltered need to have type of ResultSet
```

Question:

1. How to get a list of distinct values from a column in ResultSet without looping?
2. Does `ResultSet` has a filter function? Or does it need to be converted to a Scala collection?

Comment: You are trying to project imperative approach in scala, which is not the right way to do. Try use slick: Here some comments regarding this: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/201 In slick you can evaluated results as scala collections and this will give you a lot of opportunities to work on data in these collection., including distinct, ordering etc

Comment: slick looks very good and I will definitely use it in the future. However, now I need to fix the issue asap. Maybe I should convert the `ResultSet` to a Scala collection type so I can do it functionally?

Comment: Actually, I cannot convert it to other collection types. I will need the ResultSet to feed the openCsv method.

Comment: Converting to scala collection will be a good idea.  But there is already a lot of small issue here and there in code snippet you provided

Comment: What're the issues? I wrote a lot of comments to describe the problem needed to be resolved.

Comment: Try read next post, hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243725/implicit-conversion-of-resultset-for-queries

Comment: I take `getRows` is a stored procedure, why not make the distinct in it? Anyways, regardless, you will need to turn ResultSet into a collection, once that is done you can indeed just use `.distinct` in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one since you require the output to be another instance of ResultSet. But I think it's possible with a little bit of a hack:

```
class FilteredResultSet(wrapped: ResultSet, f: ResultSet => Boolean) extends ResultSet {
  override def next(): Boolean = {
    var result = wrapped.next()
    while (result && !f(wrapped)) {
      result = wrapped.next()
    }
    result
  }

  override def absolute(x: Int) = wrapped.absolute(x)
  override def afterLast(): Unit = wrapped.afterLast()
  // ... delegate all other ResultSet methods ...
}
```

Not super-idiomatic-functional scala, but that's typical when integrating with java libraries.

If you want to also collect the values of some column at the same time, you might do something like:

```
val categories = scala.mutable.Set.empty[String]
val filter: ResultSet => Boolean = { rs =>
  val c = rs.getString("Category")
  categories += c
  c == someTargetCategory
}
val resultRs: ResultSet = new FilteredResultSet(rs, filter)
```

Again, a bit dirty, but it gets the job done. When dealing with java libraries, I think it's kind of silly to be strict about scala functional style. There's no reason not to write a `while` loop or a function with side-effects every once in a while.